# fx2lp interfaced with image sensor

Tags: windows, visual-studio, usb

I am working on fx2lp and image sensor.i have done with fx2lp firmware code(keiluvision2) and displaying image data in the windows side with our GUI(VISUAL STUDIO C#).

Image display is working fine with the windows XP, but same firmware, hardware and software does not work with windows 10.1 pro. That means, frame rate is too slow.

What is the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress did not released LX2FP driver for newer version of Microsoft Windows.

If you want to work with Windows 10, the Windows should recognize the USB and this occurs when its driver is installed. You do not have the corresponding driver, so it does not work.

[AN65209](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an65209-getting-started-fx2lp) has some Windows drivers for LX2FP.